# Is it possible to store date as meta_key in wordpress?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to store dates and holidays in post_meta in wordpress database. I made a custom post type to store this data. So in table wp_post, I store _event_date = date and _event_holiday = holiday. The problem is that I can't query which date has the holiday I want to query. So I was thinking to store the dates in "meta_key" fields, but they say the values that are stored in meta_keys needs to have underscore. So I am hesitate to do it.

My current codes is as follows.

This is how I store my current data in wp_postmeta.

```
add_post_meta($post->ID, "_event_name", $_POST["_event_name"]);
add_post_meta($post->ID, "_event_date", $_POST["_event_date"]);
```

This is what I want to do instead.

```
add_post_meta($post->ID, $_POST[_event_date], $_POST["_event_name"]);
```

Would this method have problems with wordpress or something?

Comment: [what about this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22142801/saving-custom-fields-in-wp-postmeta/22161666#22161666) ?

Answer (score 2):

You may use it without underscore like this

```
add_post_meta($post->ID, $_POST['event_date'], $_POST['event_name']);
```

But, if you need to store using a preceding `underscore` then you may use it and there won't be any problem. BTW, you have this:

```
add_post_meta($post->ID, $_POST[_event_date], $_POST["_event_name"]);
```

You should use quotes (single/double) `$_POST['_event_date']` if this is not a typo.

Comment: I'm sorry it is just a typo. Anyway, the $_POST['_event_date'] is a date value eg,. 1-1-2014, so there will be no problem even if date is the value stored in meta_key?

Comment: Using `add_post_meta($post->ID, $_POST[_event_date], $_POST["_event_name"]);` will result in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22161666/1244126)

Comment: so no problem at all? I'm having problem with querying the holidays based on date. So if I stored them separately, the holiday is not dependent on the date. :(

Comment: @user2901740 - you should use meta_query for that, for example `<?php query_posts('cat=11&posts_per_page=10&order=DESC&meta_key=_event_name&meta_value='.$value);?>` [see also here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657824/wp-query-filter-through-meta-key-and-meta-value)

Comment: @user2901740 look comment above (also the link) and also look at the "related" links to the right ----->>>

Comment: hmm, I'm confused with the meta_query, All I want to have is an sql like this "SELECT holiday from table WHERE date= 'date'". Something like this. So I was thinking to store the date on the meta_key instead of _event_date and the holiday on the meta_value meaning they are on the same row. is it possible sir????

Comment: You can use [meta_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query).